# Return response from PHP to Jquery using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am submitting info to be saved in a MySQL database using Jquery/AJAX and PHP.
This is what i've done so far:

```
function Addinfo() {
    var ew = document.getElementById("ew").value;
    var mw = document.getElementById("mw").value;
    var dataString = 'ew1=' + ew + '&mw=' + mw;
    if (ew == '' || mw == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "ajaxadd.php",
            data : dataString,
            dataType : 'text',
            cache : false,
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#message1').html(data);
        })
    }
    return false;
}
```

and my PHP code:

```
<?php
$ew2 = $_POST['ew1'];
$mw2 = $_POST['mw1'];
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("tp", $connection);
if (isset($_POST['ew1'])) {
    $query = mysql_query("insert into table(ew, mw) values ('$ew2', '$mw2')");
    $addresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ew` = '" . $_POST['ew1'] . "' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
    $aircraft = mysql_fetch_assoc($addresult);
    echo $aircraft;
}
mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
```

It saves the information to the database successfully but I can't even get a success message let alone a variable from the PHP. I have read countless posts about asynchronous calls, callback functions and promises but I somehow can't get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$aircraft` will be an array and you are using `echo` instead of `print_r()`. Try `print_r();`

Comment: @AnkiiG Thanks. I tried that just now but I still can't get a response.

Comment: instead of print_r use only simple success message with echo.

Comment: You should really be using prepared statements for your SQL. As your code stand right now you are wide open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I see, I am a complete beginner so I had completely overlooked any security issues. Thanks I will look into it at a later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery: (main.js file)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.ajaxform').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            // give your form the method POST
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            // give your action attribute the value ajaxadd.php
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            // remove all errors
            $('input').removeClass('error').next('.errormessage').html('');

            // if there are no errors and there is a result
            if(!response.errors && response.result) {
                // success
                // loop through result and append values in message1 div
                $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                    $('#message1').append(index + ': ' + value + '<br/>');
                });

            } else {

                // append the error to the form
                $.each(response.errors, function( index, value) {
                    // add error classes
                    $('input[name*='+index+']').addClass('error').after('<div class="errormessage">'+value+'</div>')
                });

            }
        });

    });

});
```

PHP (ajaxadd.php file)

```
<?php
    // assign your post value
    $inputvalues = $_POST;

    // assign result vars
    $errors = false;
    $returnResult = false;

    $mysqli = new mysqli('host', "db_name", "password", "database");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    // escape your values
    foreach ($inputvalues as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $inputvalues[$key] = htmlspecialchars( $mysqli->real_escape_string( $value ) );
        } else {
            $errors[$key] = 'The field '.$key.' is empty';
        }
    }

    if( !$errors ) {

        // insert your query
        $mysqli->query("
            INSERT INTO `table`(`ew`, `mw`) 
            values ('".$inputvalues['ew1']."', '".$inputvalues['mw']."')
        ");

        // select your query
        // this is for only one row result
        $addresult = "
            SELECT * 
            FROM `table` 
            WHERE `ew` = '".$inputvalues['ew1']."' 
            ORDER BY `id` DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ";

        if( $result = $mysqli->query($addresult) ) {
            // collect results
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                // assign to new array
                // make returnResult an array for multiple results
                $returnResult = $row;
            }
        }
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    // print result for ajax request
    echo json_encode(['result' => $returnResult, 'errors' => $errors]);

    exit;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Ajax form submit</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>


        <form class="ajaxform" action="ajaxadd.php" method="POST">

            <input type="text" name="ew1" />
            <input type="text" name="mw" />

            <button type="submit">Submit via ajax</button>

        </form>

        <div id="message1"></div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried this and for some reason it throws the "fill in all fields" error.

Comment: @Rahkal I wasn't sure how to view the results because it was not showing so i bypassed the ajax part and submitted straight to the php file. it showed this: array (size=0) empty boolean false boolean false

Comment: I changed the answer for validation of the fields, because the names of your input form fields will fail, can you try it again?

Comment: @Bruno By the way you can watch any ajax request in your console. Open your console, then go to the network tab. Here you can watch all requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It is not adding the data to the db. The  response in the console under Network as you suggested says "{"result":false,"error":null}"

Comment: @Bruno have you tried to run the queries with a separate program like phpmyadmin, sequal pro etc? Secondly what are your post values? In your network tab please check your header > request payload

Comment: the queries run fine when I use phpmyadmin. I don't see the request payload feature, i'm googling to find out what else it could be called on Chrome.

Comment: Ok, i'll test the script for you and come back with any modifications.

Comment: This answer is now tested and working. please comeback with any feedback. :)

Comment: It seems to be submitting directly to PHP (not using ajax). On submit, it shows the php page with the values.

Comment: Please check if the jquery in main.js is loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, it works perfectly now! I really appreciate it Rakhal :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxadd.php",
        ew1:ew,
        mw1:mw,
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
    })
```

Comment: Try this one you could not set the value of ew1 and mw1 in jquery ajax

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: He means that `ew1` and `mw1` are not properties of `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your php code as below instead of directly return mysql_fetch_assoc because it returns only the first row of your SQL result.

```
<?php
$ew2 = $_POST['ew1'];
$mw2 = $_POST['mw1'];
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("tp", $connection);

if (isset($_POST['ew1']))
{
    $result = array();
    $query = mysql_query("insert into table(ew, mw) values ('$ew2', '$mw2')");
    $addresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ew` = '" . $_POST['ew1'] . "' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($aircraft = mysql_fetch_assoc($addresult))
    {
        $result[] = $aircraft;
    }
    #echo $aircraft; // wait until whole result is collected
    echo json_encode($result);
}

mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed

?>
```

Also you should edit your javascript code as below;

```
function Addinfo() {
    var ew = document.getElementById("ew").value;
    var mw = document.getElementById("mw").value;
    var dataString = 'ew1=' + ew + '&mw=' + mw;
    if (ew == '' || mw == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "ajaxadd.php",
            data : dataString,
            dataType : 'text',
            cache : false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                //$('#message1').html(data);
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

In addition advice you may check $connection and $db for successful initialization of your database connection and database selection, and again an advice for your php code your should use mysqli extension instead of mysql extension which deprecated. You can just replace mysql part of your calling methods with mysqli. Also @RakhalImming's advice is quite good for security of your code.

Comment: Please escape any post values in your answer

Comment: I tried that now and the query is successful but I still don't get any response.

Comment: @RakhalImming yes it should be escaped but its not the answer of that question

Comment: @Bruno please can you provide the console output of your ajax request from your browser via F12 ?

Comment: @Bruno I have edited my answer which may useful information for your issue

Comment: @CihanUygun There is no output as far as I can tell

Comment: @Bruno oh I noticed another issue for your javascript code and the edit for my answer is upcoming in a min

Comment: @CihanUygun Thank you. My browser console is still not outputting anything.

Comment: @Bruno you welcome, again I edited the answer in this situaion if your ajax call works browser should show an alert message, if not there is someting wrong out of this scope (ex: no jQuery library in your html or Addinfo is not firing in your browser or if (ew == '' || mw == '')  condition's else not hit.

Comment: @CihanUygun It gives me an error alert now, but the data is added to the database anyway. I'll have to try and find out where the error is. It's weird because it adds the data successfully but still throws the error now.

Comment: @Bruno in this situation you can clearly focus on your php code, I think your code throws exception or something like that so your javascript code fires error event of $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

In PHP code at the end where you

`echo $aircraft` change it to `echo json_encode($aircraft);` and in AJAX fucntion where you mentioned

`cache:false` include `success:function(response){alert response;}`

It will give your aircraft variable value in AJAX function.
Good Luck!

Comment: In Ajax you will have to set dataType to 'json'

Comment: oh yeah that too. `dataType: "json",`

Comment: when you mention `echo json_encode($aircraft);` in PHP , mention `die;` after it. like this `echo json_encode($aircraft); die;`